# PrimeNG DataTable multiselect filter with dynamic values

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I am using PrimeNG 4.x.x supporting Angular 4. I want to provide values dynamically to multiselect filter in DataTable column.

As shown below I am creating table columns dynamically from 'clientcolumnDefs' and now I want to provide values dynamically to multiselect filter Option .

```html
<p-dataTable #clientTable [value]="clientrowData" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedClient" dataKey="id" [contextMenu]="cm">
   <p-column *ngFor="let col of clientcolumnDefs" [field]="col.field" [header]="col.header" sortable="true" [filter]="true" filterMatchMode="in" [style]="{'overflow':'visible'}">
    <ng-template pTemplate="filter" let-col>
     <p-multiSelect  [options]="dynamicaFilters" defaultLabel="All" (onChange)="dt.filter($event.value,col.field,col.filterMatchMode)" styleClass="ui-column-filter"></p-multiSelect>
    </ng-template>
   </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

How do i populate my **dynamicFilters** in typescript , so that it works for all the columns.

The filters should be of this type but the values will be dynamic for each column.

[filter image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdqzP.png)

Comment: I want similar functionality for primeng <p-table>

Answer (score 2):

dynamicaFilters should be a multi dimensional array. In your ts file you need to fetch the distinct values per column and insert them into a temp array and then insert that temp array into dynamicaFilters.

Your html code will also change to be -

```
<p-column *ngFor="let col of clientcolumnDefs; let i= index" [field]="col.field" [header]="col.header" sortable="true" [filter]="true" filterMatchMode="in" [style]="{'overflow':'visible'}">
            <ng-template pTemplate="filter" let-col>
                <p-multiSelect  [options]="dynamicaFilters[i]" defaultLabel="All" (onChange)="dt.filter($event.value,col.field,col.filterMatchMode)" styleClass="ui-column-filter"></p-multiSelect>
            </ng-template>
        </p-column>
```

I did not get a chance to try this myself, let me know if you have any questions.